# What's the difference between \r and \015?

Tags: ascii, octal

I have found out that 015 is an octal code. Then what is the term for "\r"? What kind of system is that? And why isn't there a system where I just enter the decimal value of the ASCII table, like e.g. "\13" for a carriage return?

Comment: What language are you talking about?

Comment: uh, any language? specifially I started wondering because I'm using linux' tr command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why isn't there a system where I just enter the decimal value of the ASCII table, like e.g. "\13" for a carriage return?

For historical reasons, most systems allow direct representation of characters in hexadecimal and/or octal

This is because although humans used to base 10 find decimal easier, octal and hexadecimal are easier to understand at the bit level

Each octal digit is exactly 3 bits and each hexadecimal digit is 4 bits, whereas base 10 digits do not not exactly fit a fixed number of bits

If you wish to make arbitary characters based on decimal codes, there is usually function for this.  For example in python

```
python -c 'print chr(13)'
```

This will output the carriage return character you are interested in

Comment: I see, thank you. And I think the answer to my other question is: the "system" in general is called "escape sequences". Octal escape sequences are a subset of the accepted escape sequences. With octal escape sequences you can reach any symbol from the ASCII table. But you can also use a shortcut letter IF one exists / is supported. So there is redundancy and "\r" is a shortcut to reach ASCII symbol "\015".

Comment: @Robert, leaving aside whether the escapes are interpreted by your shell before being passed to tr, and assuming tr works somewhat like C (as many programs do),  \r would represent a carriage return, no matter what the source character encoding is; \015 would represent the character code for whatever the source character encoding is,which is not necessarily ASCII.